# Copy android development environment to another comp (windows)

Tags: android, windows

Is there any quick way to copy eclipse and android development environment from one windows computer to another? Will it work just to copy and paste android, java and eclipse folders? Or will I have to waste hours installing?

Comment: I think you are talking about this: [Android - install android tools/plugin easy way(offline)](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-install-android-toolsplugin-easy-way-offline/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android SDK is self-contained so you should be able to just copy it. Eclipse is also self-contained, but you'll need to update it's settings to tell it where the android SDK is on the new pc. You can do this in project > properties > android

You can probably copy the Java Development Kit, but you might need to properly install the Java Runtime Environment.

Answer (score 2):

not needed to install again just copy folders & just configure the paths in system variables